# Finite sum of $1/n^{\delta}$

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion

How does one show
$\sum_{n \leq x/M} \frac{1}{n^{\delta}} \approx \frac{(N/M)^{\delta}}{1-\delta}$, where $n \leq N$ and $\delta>0$.

I assume this has something to do with Taylor series, but im not sure around what number.

It also might be useful to use the Euler-Mac Laurin summation formula...

Comment: Is your sum from $n=1$ to $\frac xM$?  If so, shouldn't the sum depend on $x$?  Or does $N=\frac xM$?  Please clarify.  It looks like it comes from turning the sum into an integral.

Comment: These are the generalized harmonic numbers. I suspect that they wouldn't grow like any power of $x/M$.

Comment: Do you also want $\delta<1?$  Otherwise the right-sand side would be negative.